# Swift 3 JSON NSFastEnumerationIterator has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift

Im using Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.0. I am able to print out the entire response but I am having trouble looping through and printing out each value. I am getting a " Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members when I try to print out 'title' below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
         if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let datas = dict["data"] as? NSArray{
                for data in datas{
                    print("DEVELOPER: \(data)")
                        if let title = data["myTitle"] as? String{
                            print(title)
                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not getting your question properly!!

Comment: @KetanParmar I get an error that says "Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members". The error happens when I am trying to print 'title'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use native Swift `Array`. Use **always** Swift native types unless you have absolutely no choice. `NSArray` lacks type information so the compiler cannot infer that the array contains dictionaries.

```
if let datas = dict["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was absolutely it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you wanna keep your data as structured, all you have to do is check for the dictionary itself while in loop like the following:

```
for apple in apples { 
 if let _ = apple as? [String:AnyObject] {
// do whatever you like here
   }
 }
```

Comment: I agree, but using an array [[String:AnyObject]] would deprive you from all the useful functions attached to it. Adding, removing, finding at index and etc...