# Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-dictionary

I've found an exact solution for above error here [http://stackoverflow.com/q/39429342/5309431](http://www.example.com/) and I try to execute that in my code. But the issue is not solved. I don't know what I've made wrong. Please Help

```
for dict in self.levelRefArr{
  if let datas = dict["data"] as? [[String:Any]] { //Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members
      print(datas)
   }                   
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`levelrpfarr` is most likely `Any`, you need to cast it to the actual type which tells the compiler the type of the items in the array

```
for dict in self.levelRefArr as! [[String:Any]] { ...
```

Comment: It's working thank you so much but am getting warning " Cast from 'NSMutableArray' to unrelated type '[[String : Any]]' always fails"  is this will cause problem?

Comment: Yes, it will cause problem. Don't use `NSMutableArray` at all, use always Swift native `Array`.