# GET request on new Alamofire Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

So I decided to migrate my App to Swift 3.0 but now I am seeing myself unable to solve a problem I´m facing with a .GET request with the new Alamofire. This is the request right now:

```
func getAlbums(_ ID: String, ANN: String, completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
        let searchFT = ID.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
        let urlPath = ""
        let url = URL(string: urlPath)

        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value as! [String: AnyObject]! {
                if let dict = JSON["results"] as! NSArray! {
                    AlbumsArtist.removeAll()
                    AlbumsArtist = [String]()
                    ImagesArtist.removeAll()
                    ImagesArtist = [String]()
                    for items in dict {


                        if let AT = items["artistName"] as? String {
                            if AT == ANN {
                                if let TN = items["collectionName"] as? String {
                                    AlbumsArtist.append(TN)
                                } else {
                                    AlbumsArtist.append("")
                                }

                                if let IM = items["artworkUrl100"] as? String {
                                    let newString = IM.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("100", withString: "600", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                                    ImagesArtist.append(newString)
                                } else {
                                    ImagesArtist.append("")
                                }
                            }
                        }




                    }

                    completed()

                }

            }

            }
        }
```

The problem that I am getting is with if let `AT = items["artistName"] as? String` the error says this: `Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element (aka: 'Any') has no subscript members`

Thank you very much!

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39429455/5327882

Comment: @ronatory Fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you should change your code to:

```
if let AT = items["artistName"] as? [[String:Any]]
```

But to make your code more safe you should use the following:

```
if let AT = items["artistName"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    if AT == ANN {
        guard let TN = items["collectionName"] as? String,
              let IM = items["artworkUrl100"] as? String else { // Some error occurred }

        AlbumsArtist.append(TN);
        let newString = IM.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("100", withString: "600", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        ImagesArtist.append(newString)
    }
}
```